# Response data from observable on calling the API showing data in console but not rendering in template angular 10

Tags: angular, typescript, angular10

I am trying to load the response from the API into the view. A very simple task, but got stuck in an issue really bad.

```
myItems: any[] = [];

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

ngOnInit() {
this.http
  .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
  .subscribe((res: any[]) => {
    this.myItems = res;
    console.log("in call api : ", this.myItems);
  });
 }
```

I get the items from the API and store the result in an array and In my template, just print all the array.

```
<ul>
 <li *ngFor="let i of myItems">
  {{ i.id }}
 </li>
</ul>
```

The problem is that the data shows in the view some time and sometimes it doesn't. And in the TS file, it always shows the result in the console. Also, If the list didn't appear the first time then as soon as I click the page link again, the list appears on the template. Even If I click on some dropdown in the nav, the list appears on the view. I am using Metronic theme for my application. This is just a simple task and I have tried this on a basic angular app and it works completely fine. Can't figure out what's happening here. I'd really appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: what does the console output say?  is it json?

Comment: Console outputs the array of items but when I try to render this array template nothing happens.

Comment: Please post your code instead of images

Comment: i wonder if you could try without the | json in the template and see what happens, or maybe see if you get a different result in OnInit instead of the constructor maybe?

Comment: The issue is solved. I did this by changing ChangeDetectionStrategy. It was set to onPush. I changed this to default settings and angular started change detection by default again.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your http call in `ngOnInit() {}` and make your component implement `onInit`.

Dont use the constructor unless there's really no other way. Use Angulars lifecycle hooks instead.

https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

Comment: I've updated the question, Please see again my issue. Thank you.